# EGL: EGL_SURFACE_TYPE and rendering to a texture

Tags: egl

I am writing an head-less Linux application which uses EGL interface to perform OpenGL drawing. I use "render to a texture" approach, i.e. I don't create any pbuffers or pixmaps inside EGL world. Instead, I call `eglMakeCurrent()` as the following:

```
eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL_NO_SURFACE, context);
```

and then attach a texture to the framebuffer.

Now, I wonder what is the proper (most portable) way to specify required `EGL_SURFACE_TYPE` value in `configAttribs` when I do `eglChooseConfig()`?

[eglChooseConfig() documentation](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/sdk/docs/man/html/eglChooseConfig.xhtml) says that the default `EGL_SURFACE_TYPE` is `EGL_WINDOW_BIT`. At the same time it says about masking, i.e. looking for configs supporting both `EGL_WINDOW_BIT | EGL_PIXMAP_BIT`. It is unclear to me whether `0` is a valid mask value here? Or `0` is defaulted to `EGL_WINDOW_BIT`? The second question if `EGL` standard prescribes that the some surface type must be always supported by arbitrary implementation? So, what should I do to always find a config?

Comment: "*Now, I wonder what is the proper (most portable) way to specify required EGL_SURFACE_TYPE value in configAttribs when I do eglChooseConfig()?*" Why do you need to? Why isn't using EGL_NO_SURFACE sufficient? The [extension spec that those enums come from seems to think that it is](https://www.khronos.org/registry/EGL/extensions/KHR/EGL_KHR_surfaceless_context.txt).

Comment: @NicolBolas `eglChooseConfig()` is a part of standard workflow, it is required to obtain `config` for `eglCreateContext()`. So I must choose some config in any way.

Comment: My point is that the EGL surface doesn't seem to come from eglCreateContext. It seems to come from the window onto which you make it current. So if you don't use a window, what do those flags matter?

Comment: This flags matter because I must ask for something specific and there may be no such configs, For instance, at VirtIO GPU virtual device, there is only `EGL_WINDOW_BIT` supported.